# Set offset value of a DIV in % of total width of the screen

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(indent);
$(window).resize(indent);
function indent() {
    $("div:nth-of-type(odd)").offset({left: 100});
};
```

It is working absolutely fine but the only problem is that the value *100* is in pixel but I want it to be *10%* (in %) like:

```
$(document).ready(indent);
$(window).resize(indent);
function indent() {
    $("div:nth-of-type(odd)").offset({left: 10%});
};
```

But the above code is not working.
How could I set the offset value in % of the total width of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left and top values for [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2) are provided as numeric (pixel) values, the method does not accept percentages.

You need to determine the width of the window `$(window).width()` and divide this by 10. For example:

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();
$("div:nth-of-type(odd)").offset({left: (winWidth / 10)});
```